# Choose between hasMany and belongsToMany relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

**Background Information:**

I'm building an event management system for a sound company. It will allow them to better allocate their personnel. The company can be hired to provide sound reinforcement for many events.

An event can have many shifts. A shift is for setting up the equipment, running the show, and taking down the equipment.

Then, a shift is fulfilled by users who can hold many positions in the shift.

The user, on the other hand, can hold many positions.

**NOTE: A user is not limited to a single position in the shift.**

---

**What I want:**

I hardcoded some HTML to get the output I desire. I will attach the pictures below.

[image: shift1]
[image: shift2]
[image: shift3]

Basically, I want the admins of the company to sign up a user into a shift. In order to fulfill the necessary positions.

---

**The Problem:**

I think I have the database design correct but I'm still debating where to use a belongsToMany relationship and hasMany relationship.

Here is my initial database design:

[image: Initial database design]

Comment: I think you will have more success to receive a reliable answer if you post this question at [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)